# (0 , _native.createStackNavigator) is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am working on the Expo basic chat app, and I need to use Stack Navigator, which I updated manually to 4.x. When I do that, however, it gives me the error message: `(0 , _native.createStackNavigator) is not a function`

This is app.js:

```js
import Main from './components/Main';
import Chat from './components/Chat';
// Import React Navigation
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native'
// Create the navigator
const navigator = createStackNavigator({
  Main: { screen: Main },
  Chat: { screen: Chat },
});
// Export it as the root component
export default navigator
```

Here is main.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput, // 1. <- Add this 
  View,
} from 'react-native';

class Main extends React.Component {
  state = { name: '' } // 2. <- Add the component state
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.nameInput}
          placeHolder="John Cena"
          value={this.state.name}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const offset = 24;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  nameInput: { // 3. <- Add a style for the input
    height: offset * 2,
    margin: offset,
    paddingHorizontal: offset,
    borderColor: '#111111',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
});
```

Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Update to react navigation 5.x, the `import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native'` is a syntax for 5.x, you are using 4.x